# What do I call this curve

Tags: curves

What sort of curve is defined by this sequence (every number is 2/3 of the previous number, but the 2/3 value is arbitrary - it could be anything between 0 and 1 exclusive)

100, 66, 44, 29, 19, 13, ...

Is is exponential? geometric?

EDIT - 
I rounded the numbers because adding a ton of precision only clouds the question. If this is troublesome, just pretend I didn't round the numbers and that each is exactly a multiple of 2/3 of the previous.

Comment: The example sequence does not have $2/3$ exactly, nor even the same ratio each time.  Hence the most we can call this is a "nonincreasing sequence" (provided the first term is positive).

Answer (score 1):

A sequence where $a_n=br^n$ is called geometric of ratio $r$.